# Your active platform is: default_platform, but the corresponding property "platforms.default_platform.home" is not found

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8, netbeans-8, javafx-3d

Im currently developing JavaFX applications. I used Netbeans 7.4 before but now I switch to Netbeans 8.0.2. After running my project with the new IDE, an error occured saying:

```
C:\projects\client\QueueBoard\nbproject\build-impl.xml:87: The J2SE Platform is not correctly set up.
Your active platform is: default_platform, but the corresponding property "platforms.default_platform.home" is not found in the project's properties files. 
Either open the project in the IDE and setup the Platform with the same name or add it manually.
For example like this:
ant -Duser.properties.file=<path_to_property_file> jar (where you put the property "platforms.default_platform.home" in a .properties file)
or ant -Dplatforms.default_platform.home=<path_to_JDK_home> jar (where no properties file is used)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

How do you resolve this?

Comment: Right click the project node, select "Properties" from the popup menu, select "Libraries" from the dialog.  In the "Java Platform" combobox, select a valid platform.  If for some reason, there's nothing there, try clicking "Manage Platforms" and either add a new one or correct the path issues with the exist/default one...

Comment: I did what you suggested, java platform is set to JDK 1.8. It didn't worked!

Comment: I think, the problem here is the build-impl.xml, maybe there is a misconfiguration after opening it with the latest IDE.. What do you think?

Comment: Possible.  You could close the project and then delete the `build.xml` file (not the `-impl.xml`!) and then re-open the project...Make sure you do a clean and build afterwards...Also, I sometimes just cycle the platform value, open the combobox and select another value, if there are no other values, this seems to work as well..

Comment: It didn't worked as well.. Oh men! Im stuck!.. Please help!!!!

Comment: Grab the source, delete the project, start again...

Comment: Sometimes, the only way to split a pea is to use a thermal nuclear device!

Comment: I think a very similar problem (with solution) is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455793/the-j2se-platform-is-not-correctly-set-up-netbeans-ide-8-0-2/48418101#48418101

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to resolve this problem is:

1. open the Project in NetBeans
2. open Project-Settings for this project
3. check (and maybe correct/fix) all settings (including Platform-Settings)
4. click on Save/OK in settings dialog
5. Clean+Build project

By doing this, project-settings-file will be updated to current settings.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I encountered this recently.  The solution I came up with is to modify the user-editable `build.xml` file (which is usually one directory up from build-impl.xml) and add the following after the `<import>` of `build-impl.xml`:

```
<property name="platforms.default_platform.home"
          location="${java.home}/.."/>
```

This allows any user/local settings to have precedence, but if not defined, the java used should be the same java that is executing Ant.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still exists in Netbeans 15 and can be solved by updating the `nbproject/private/private.properties` file and ensure this row exists:

```
javac.debug=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me (NB 17, in 2023) after I updated my Java installation, just a minor version update. Projects created (using Ant) before the update would obviously not run because the JDK home directory had changed, but when I used Netbeans Resolve References dialog I started to see these messages about `default_platform`. However newly created projects were fine and they had the exact same references to `default_platform` (in the `project.properties` file)

Ensuring that `javac.debug=true` exists as recommended elsewhere did not help (why would it?), and it seems wrong that I'd have to edit `build-impl.xml` given that it worked before and other projects are fine.

I also deleted NB cache but this did not help.

What I did was to create another Java platform (using `Tools|Java Platform`) with the same JDK home as the default one. Then I had `JDK 17` and `JDK 17 (Default)`. I switched my project over to the `JDK 17` platform and that fixed the problem.