# The J2SE Platform is not correctly set up.( NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 )

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am getting this error while running my program in NetBeans.

```
nt -f D:\\PMT_LandingPage jfxsa-run
D:\PMT_LandingPage\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3725: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\PMT_LandingPage\nbproject\build-impl.xml:87: The J2SE Platform is not correctly set up.
 Your active platform is: default_platform, but the corresponding property "platforms.default_platform.home" is not found in the project's properties files. 
 Either open the project in the IDE and setup the Platform with the same name or add it manually.
 For example like this:
     ant -Duser.properties.file=<path_to_property_file> jar (where you put the property "platforms.default_platform.home" in a .properties file)
  or ant -Dplatforms.default_platform.home=<path_to_JDK_home> jar (where no properties file is used)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am new with NetBeans and really don't know how to fix it. I googled this issue but could not get any solution.

Comment: Do you have load your Java Development Kit (JDK) loaded right?

Comment: Which JDK are you using? Does it support JavaFX? How did you start the build? From the command line or from within NetBeans?

Comment: I am using jdk 7.0.40

Comment: Please improve the title of your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Tools -> Java Platforms`and select the correct path to your JDK.

Comment: I had this error and then added another platform under Tools -> Java Platforms, just to be able to select another Platform under Project -> Properties.
After that, I switched back to the original platform, and the error was gone! That saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

ant uses a variable named `platform.active` for identifiying the java home path. Netbeans should initialize that variable with the correct path, and indeed it does depending on your selected java platform.
But, if you select the default platform, netbeans does not assign the correct path to that variable. Instead its value become `default_platform`.
So, in order to correctly find the java path, you should probably change a line like this:

```
<webproject1:property
  name="platform.home"
  value="platforms.${platform.active}.home"/>
```

into something like this:

```
<condition
  property="platform.home"
  value="${java.home}/../"
  else="platforms.${platform.active}.home">
      <equals arg1="${platform.active}" arg2="default_platform" />
</condition>
```

This checks the value of `platform.active` and use it, if it is a path, or use the value of `java.home` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tested all of above answers but no one worked for me, the only solution worked for me is replacing below line in file `build-impl.xml`:

```
<j2seproject1:property name="platform.home" value="platforms.${platform.active}.home"/>
```

to:

```
<j2seproject1:property name="platform.home" value="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-14.0.2"/>
```